# Counter in nested for-each in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, soa

I'm wondering is there any way to create a global counter in a XSL transformation..

The case is that currently I'm using a nested loop to group and loop over orders and items.
Here is a sample input:

```
<shipment>
    <shipmentid>1111222</shipmentid>
    <context>TEST</context>
    <delivery>
        <deliveryItem>
            <deliveryNumber>123</deliveryNumber>
            <deliveryDate>...</deliveryDate>
            <arrivalDate>...</arrivalDate>
            <customerOrderNumber>X999</customerOrderNumber>
            <customerItemCode>MC423</customerItemCode>
        </deliveryItem>
        <deliveryItem>
            <deliveryNumber>123</deliveryNumber>
            <deliveryDate>...</deliveryDate>
            <arrivalDate>...</arrivalDate>
            <customerOrderNumber>X877</customerOrderNumber>
            <customerItemCode>AY642</customerItemCode>
        </deliveryItem>
        <deliveryItem>
            <deliveryNumber>123</deliveryNumber>
            <deliveryDate>...</deliveryDate>
            <arrivalDate>...</arrivalDate>
            <customerOrderNumber>X315</customerOrderNumber>
            <customerItemCode>XY223</customerItemCode>
        </deliveryItem>
        <deliveryItem>
            <deliveryNumber>123</deliveryNumber>
            <deliveryDate>...</deliveryDate>
            <arrivalDate>...</arrivalDate>
            <customerOrderNumber>X315</customerOrderNumber>
            <customerItemCode>MM647</customerItemCode>
        </deliveryItem>
    </delivery>
</shipment>
```

The expected output should look somewhat like this (not taking in any of the details):

```
<Order>
     <ControlHeader>HL</ControlHeader>
     <HL01>1</HL01>
</Order>
<Item>
    <ItemHierarchicalLevel>
       <ControlHeader>HL</ControlHeader>
       <HL01>2</HL01>
    </ItemHierarchicalLevel>
</Item>
<Item>
    <ItemHierarchicalLevel>
       <ControlHeader>HL</ControlHeader>
       <HL01>3</HL01>
    </ItemHierarchicalLevel>
</Item>
<Item>
    <ItemHierarchicalLevel>
       <ControlHeader>HL</ControlHeader>
       <HL01>4</HL01>
    </ItemHierarchicalLevel>
</Item>
<Order>
     <ControlHeader>HL</ControlHeader>
     <HL01>5</HL01>
</Order>
<Item>
    <ItemHierarchicalLevel>
       <ControlHeader>HL</ControlHeader>
       <HL01>6</HL01>
    </ItemHierarchicalLevel>
</Item>
```

And currently this is the structure for the nested for-each I'm using, to group the orders and output line details:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="/shipment/delivery/deliveryItem" group-by="customerOrderNumber">
  <tns:Order>
     <tns:ControlHeader>HL</tns:ControlHeader>
     <tns:HL01>
      
     </tns:HL01>
  </tns:Order>
  <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
        <tns:Item>
            <tns:ItemHierarchicalLevel>
               <tns:ControlHeader>HL</tns:ControlHeader>
               <tns:HL01>
                  
               </tns:HL01>
            </tns:ItemHierarchicalLevel>
        </tns:Item>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Is there any way to create a numeral sequence I could use in the HL01 field, that is the same for both Order and Item loop and continues incrementing with each iteration never resetting?
The position() function can not be used , since it is a different value in each of the loops.

Comment: You can do this in two passes: first, group the items in a variable; then apply numbering to the result. To maintain consecutive numbering across groups, you can use `xsl:number`.

Comment: Why is Oracle tagged? This appears to have nothing to do with Oracle databases.

Comment: Consider to show the attributes of `xsl:for-each-group` as well. Also, do you use an XSLT 2 or an XSLT 3 processor?

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have added the attributes to the XSLT, and i'm limited to XSLT 2.0

Comment: If you are limited to XSLT 2 then try the suggestion already made in the first comment to store the grouped item in a variable which you then process with further templates to inject the number with `xsl:number`.

Comment: Is there an element with `<tns:HL01>7</tns:HL01>` missing in your wanted result sample? It seems with four items and three groups you would end up with seven elements.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering is there any way to create a global counter in a XSL transformation

To answer this on a slightly different level: remember that XSLT is a functional language without global mutable variables, so the concept of a "global counter" is completely alien to the language. The mechanisms for numbering therefore rely on functional mechanisms: `xsl:number` examines the position of a given node with the input tree, `position()` returns the position of an item within the sequence of items you are processing. So the simple answer to your question is "no"; you have to find a different solution to your requirement.

Comment: In XSLT 3 an accumulator can serve as a counter, so there I don't see the global counter as completely alien.

Comment: An accumulator, like xsl:number, can be used to maintain state (e.g. a counter) with respect to your position in one particular input document. It can't track global state, or the state of your output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of using `xsl:number` in the second pass:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:tns="some-url">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/shipment">
    <!-- 1st pass  -->
    <xsl:variable name="tmpResult">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="delivery/deliveryItem" group-by="customerOrderNumber">
            <tns:Order>
                <tns:ControlHeader>HL</tns:ControlHeader>
                <tns:HL01/>
            </tns:Order>
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <tns:Item>
                    <tns:ItemHierarchicalLevel>
                        <tns:ControlHeader>HL</tns:ControlHeader>
                        <tns:HL01/>
                    </tns:ItemHierarchicalLevel>
                </tns:Item>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- final output -->
    <tns:someRoot>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$tmpResult/*"/>
    </tns:someRoot>
</xsl:template>
  
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tns:HL01">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:number count="tns:Item|tns:Order"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```